# Finite Boolean ring with $1 \neq 0$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \dots \times \mathbb{Z}_2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, ring-theory, idempotents, boolean-ring

Let $R$ be a finite Boolean ring with $1 \neq 0$. Show that $R\cong \mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \dots \times \mathbb{Z}_2$.

This is exercise 2 on p267 in the book abstract algebra of Dummit and Foote. The author gives the hint to use that if $e$ is an idempotent of a ring $R$ with $1$, then

$$R \cong Re \times R(1-e)$$

where $Re$ is a ring with identity $e$ and $R(1-e)$ a ring with identity $1-e$.

**My attempt**:

If $R = \{0,1\}$, then $R \cong \mathbb{Z}_2$ is trivial.

Hence, we may assume that $\{0,1\}$ is properly contained in $R$. Thus,we can pick an element $x \notin\{0,1\}$. We obtain because every element in a Boolean ring is an idempotent:

$$R \cong Rx \times R(1-x)$$

$Rx$ is a ring with identity $x \neq 0$ and $R(1-x)$ is a ring with identity $1-x \neq 0$. Moreover, $Rx$ and $R(1-e)$ have cardinality strictly smaller than the cardinality of $R$. These rings are also Boolean. Induction yields the result. $\quad \square$

Is this correct?

Comment: I would say "yes" since what you described is just an implementation of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2428051/29335) at one of the questions I linked.

Comment: [Related and somewhat more general](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/638147/29335).